# Django views architecture

Tags: django, django-views

I'm new to django and had a question regarding organizing views. `manage.py startapp` creates a `views.py` in my app folder. But `django-admin.py startproject <name>` does not create a corresponding views.py file in the `<project_name>/<project_name>` folder.

I find it intuitive to have global views which do not correspond to a particular app. For example, a login page would and should be independent of any app that I create (its associated with the django auth app). So, would it make sense to create another views.py in the `<project_name>/<project_name>` folder where I can define such views?

(Just wanted to run it by experienced djangoers before I proceed.)

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just create a login app and put login-related views in there? (and so on...)

Comment: @Eli Sounds like a good idea actually. Would that effectively be a wrapper around the contrib auth app that django provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can write your global views anywhere. it can be in any file name (I use, global_views.py)
- I used to write a global to overrride/customize the default framework apps like custom authentication backend and custom sites.
- Better to create a custom app and write all the global views.