# Where to put the main view?

Tags: django, django-views

This is probably obvious to experienced users but I have been dealing with Django for only several days.

**Question:** Where do you put global views, i.e. for the main page?

I followed the tutorial where you only create views for an app called *polls*. And it is also written that as much stuff as possible should be put in decoupled apps to make them portable. I found nothing about a view for the main page. So should I put my main stuff in *project_name/project_name/views.py* or create a separate app, put the views in *project_name/globalapp/views.py* and then map the '^$' URL to *global.main*?

I guess I can do whatever I want but I wonder whether there is a common way to do it because it has advantages I haven't realized yet.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526256/django-views-architecture) but the answer doesn't seem to be clear about this.

Comment: You can put them anywhere.. how about a views.py at the project level?  I tend to stuff them into an app called `website`. Curious for answers as well though..

Comment: I use an app called `mainsite`, or one named after the project.

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of personal preference. My own rule-of-thumb is:

If your global pages are simple collections of links to your apps or data from them then the easiest way is to put the views for them in a file at the project level, right next to your settings.py and urls.py. You also put custom middleware and custom context processors in files in the same location.

If your global pages are any more complicated than that (for example they need their own models or forms or ...) then put them in a separate app.

Comment: I often start to add models,forms and others to my project level directory ( the one with settings.py and urls.py ). I like the idea of my project being an app on it's own. The main app!